# Using storyboard and auto-layout to position buttons by screen percentage

Tags: xcode, storyboard, autolayout, constraints, percentage

I'm trying to set up some constraints inside a view via **storyboard** (im not a fan of contrasting via code).
My main goal is kinda simple, but tricky :
**How can i align 3 buttons by PERCENTAGE using Multiplier inside a view?**

Example :
What do we see? 3 buttons inside a view. The left button is 10% from the view width(from his left side). The second one is centered , and the third one is 10% from the right side.

[image: source]

What am i trying to do?

**I want to accomplish this using only Horizontal Center in Container and Vertical Center in Container through their Multiplier**

**What have i done so far?**

Until now i tried using trailing and leading spaces constraints, the problem is that its not relative to the view size.
Any suggestions guys? I'm trying to figure this out for the last few days.

Comment: Why are you adding these arbitrary restrictions? Like only using horizontal centre etc... There is no need for those at all.

Comment: @Fogmeister , actually if theres another way or method it would be great if you could redirect me :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with a spacer view.

Add a view and add a constraint setting the width to 10% of the container width. But make this view hidden.

Now add constraints pinning it in between the container and your button.

This will act as scaffolding for your button keeping it 10% of the way in from the edge.

However, I must persuade you not to do his. It isn't standard at all. Just choose a space value and use it.

Comment: Isnt there more elegant way to achieve this? I mean percentage is something very necessary when you have different screen sizes..

Comment: The trouble is that you're setting a space to be a percentage of a width. You can set a width to be a percentage of a width very easily. You could try just setting a space of zero and then messing with the multiplier but no idea what that will do.

Comment: I'll check it out .. that kinda critical issue doesn't it?

Comment: Not really. Very easily solved with spacer views. They are used in more ways than just this too.

Comment: But my main problem is that i want to animate the left/right contrasting to the center X of the view.. and as far as i know i need to outlet X contrasting , which is in my case the Horizontal Center in Container..get it?

Comment: But if you use a spacer view then its width will update during the animation surely. It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve. You said you wanted the view 10% of the width of the supervise from the edge of the superview. A spacer view will do this for you no matter what the width is.